# Alternativas a «El presente documento» en introducciones

Tags: formalidad, redacción

A la hora de escribir las introducciones de documentos formales, artículos, trabajos, etc. se suelen escribir frases como:

- El presente documento es un...
- El presente documento versa sobre...
- El presente documento trata de...
- etc.

¿Existe alguna alternativa formal y que quede bien para reemplazar «el presente documento»? Se trataría solamente de esas tres palabras, ya que el resto de la oración ya es mucho más versátil. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es sustituir "el presente" por "este", y especificar el tipo de documento. Por ejemplo,

> La ley aplicable en caso de disputa o conflicto de interpretación de los términos que conforman **este aviso legal**
> *([Aviso legal de la Agencia Española de Protección de Datos](https://www.aepd.es/es/politica-de-privacidad-y-aviso-legal))*

> se comprometa a transportar al pasajero y a su equipaje en virtud de **este contrato**
> *([Condiciones de transporte de Iberia](https://www.iberia.com/es/condiciones-transporte/))*

Para otros tipos de documentos, frases como "este artículo", "este informe", "esta obra", etc. podrían ser válidas.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con wimi. Como traductor jurídico debo decir que, si bien "este" puede usarse, en documentos legales lo más común es encontrar "el presente". Es más: *el presente, la presente* también suelen encontrarse como adjetivos nominalizados, sin, por ejemplo, los sustantivos "documento" o "carta".

Otras alternativas formales que se me ocurren, aunque un poco más verborrágicas, constan de proposiciones relativas:

- El documento que nos ocupa ...
- El documento que tenemos ante nosotros ...
- El contrato que estamos celebrando ...
- La ley que estamos sancionando ...

(Obviamente, por su longitud estas frases no podrían usarse más que un par de veces.)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que toca preguntarse es si las alternativas inmediatas como «este documento» son informales o no. Convengamos, además, que lo «formal» lingüísticamente hablando no indica más seriedad sino que refiere a fórmulas bien estandarizadas en un contexto comunicativo. Así, «el presente documento…» sin duda es formal y «este documento» es más bien neutral (pues no es exclusivo de ningún contexto o, lo que es lo mismo, puede ser formal o informal).

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta que sugiere reemplazar la expresión por «este documento» dada su neutralidad y su simplicidad y porque también la he leído formalmente. Otros ejemplos formales que he leído en la práctica son:

> El siguiente ensayo pretende…

> A continuación, se tratará…